# Error when using speech recognition in uwp

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, uwp, speech-recognition

I am making a uwp app, which has voice search in it, I got these following codes :

I got this code from a windows blog on speech recognition:

```
          var speechRecognizer = new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer();

        //speechRecognizer.RecognitionQualityDegrading += speechRecognizer_RecognitionQualityDegrading;

        // Add a web search grammar to the recognizer.
        var webSearchGrammar = new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionScenario.WebSearch, "webSearch");


        speechRecognizer.UIOptions.AudiblePrompt = "Say what you want to search for...";
        speechRecognizer.UIOptions.ExampleText = @"Ex. 'weather for London'";
        speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(webSearchGrammar);


        // Compile the constraint.
        await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

        // Start recognition.
        Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
        await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

        // Do something with the recognition result.
        var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(speechRecognitionResult.Text, "Text spoken");
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
```

I got another bunch of code from a website:

```
async void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
    await this.recognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

    this.recognizer.Timeouts.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    this.recognizer.Timeouts.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

    this.recognizer.UIOptions.AudiblePrompt = "Say whatever you like, I'm listening";
    this.recognizer.UIOptions.ExampleText = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    this.recognizer.UIOptions.ShowConfirmation = true;
    this.recognizer.UIOptions.IsReadBackEnabled = true;
    this.recognizer.Timeouts.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    var result = await this.recognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

    if (result != null)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.AppendLine(
          $"I have {result.Confidence} confidence that you said [{result.Text}] " +
          $"and it took {result.PhraseDuration.TotalSeconds} seconds to say it " +
          $"starting at {result.PhraseStartTime:g}");

        var alternates = result.GetAlternates(10);

        builder.AppendLine(
          $"There were {alternates?.Count} alternates - listed below (if any)");

        if (alternates != null)
        {
            foreach (var alternate in alternates)
            {
                builder.AppendLine(
                  $"Alternate {alternate.Confidence} confident you said [{alternate.Text}]");
            }
        }
        this.txtResults.Text = builder.ToString();
    }
}
SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
```

altough, whenever I run these codes, they seem to throw an error.
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj8Fx.png)
can anyone pls tell how to solve this error, I searched the web for it, but did not get anything...

Comment: Have you enabled the "online speech recognition" in Windows settings under Start > Settings > Privacy > Speech? And have you enabled the microphone under the app capabilites?

Comment: yeah I just enabled it, and it is working now, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @codingjuli, could you mind convert your comment as an answer for this thread, it looks solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to enable "online speech recognition" in Windows settings under Start > Settings > Privacy > Speech.

And make sure to enabled the microphone in your app capabilities.